# How do I extract the output of Invoke-RestMethod into distinct variables

Tags: windows, rest, powershell, windows-defender

Somewhat of a Powershell noob here ..

I am working on Microsoft's API for Windows Defender ATP. I need to understand how to extract specific values from a custom powershell object which is returned as the output of Invoke-RestMethod.

```
$webResponse = Invoke-RestMethod  -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $headers 
Write-Output $webResponse
```

This produces the following:

> @odata.context                                                value 
>   --------------                                                -----  https://api.securitycenter.windows.com/api/$metadata#Machines 
>   {@{id=f7749cafd089c66e53g21332ba0b426f6f88c953;
>   computerDnsName=desktop-h2134uc; firstSeen=4/30/19 10:03:40 PM;
>   lastSeen=5/3/19 4:15:17 AM; osPlatform=Windows10;           osVersion…

My question is - how can I extract the individual field values for id, computerDnsName etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri www.google.at
$response | Get-Member
TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
...
Headers           Property   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,string]     Headers {get;}
Images            Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollection Images {get;}
InputFields       Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollection InputFields {get;}
Links             Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollection Links {get;}
ParsedHtml        Property   mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 ParsedHtml {get;}
RawContent        Property   string RawContent {get;set;}
RawContentLength  Property   long RawContentLength {get;}
RawContentStream  Property   System.IO.MemoryStream RawContentStream {get;}
Scripts           Property       Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollection Scripts {get;}
StatusCode        Property   int StatusCode {get;}
StatusDescription Property   string StatusDescription {get;}
```

Via  `Get-Member` you'll know which properties this object supports. Then you can call these properties on the given object:

```
$response.StatusCode
200
```

If you want to select multiple properties you can use `Select-Object`:

```
 $response | select statuscode, statusdescription

 StatusCode StatusDescription
 ---------- -----------------
   200 OK
```

You can, of course, store the results of `Select-Object` in a variable.

More of less the same can be used fro `Invoke-RestMethod`:

```
  Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/feed/ | Get-Member

TypeName: System.Xml.XmlElement

Name                 MemberType            Definition
----                 ----------            ----------
...

comments             Property              System.Object[] comments {get;}
creator              Property              System.Xml.XmlElement creator {get;}
description          Property              System.Xml.XmlElement description {get;}
encoded              Property              System.Xml.XmlElement encoded {get;}
```

...

The properties you can select/use depends on the format returned in the response body. In the above example, you have an XML body, but it could also be JSON or something else.